# Solving 15-puzzle algorithm using IDA* or A*

Tags: java, algorithm, sliding-tile-puzzle, a-star

I am currently using the BestFirst algorithm to solve the puzzle 15. It works well when I have a simple inputs and takes about 1-20 seconds to solve the puzzle. But when it comes to complicated inputs, it might takes forever to run. I'm just wondering if there is any way to improve my algorithm's performance.

**Main.java**

```
final int _ = 0;
State initialState = new State(
_,  1, 4,  2,  
9,  5, 3,  12, 
8,  6, 7, 11, 
14, 10, 13, 15);

cList open = new cList();
cList closed = new cList();
open.InsertFront(initialState);

while(!open.isEmpty()){
   State st = open.RemoveFront();
   closed.InsertBack(st);
   if(st.isGoal()) {showPath(st); break;}
   State[] ss = st.NextStates();
   for(State s:ss){
      if(!closed.isExist(s))
         if(!open.ExistOrSubstitue(s))
            open.InsertSorted(s);
    }
 }
```

**cList**

```
private ArrayList<State> list = new ArrayList<State>(1000);
public void InsertFront(State s){ list.add(0,s); }
public void InsertBack(State s){ list.add(s);}
public State RemoveFront(){ return list.remove(0); }
public boolean isEmpty(){ return list.isEmpty(); }
public void InsertSorted(State s){
  int i=0;
  while(i<list.size()){
    if(list.get(i).compareTo(s)>0) break;
    i++;
  }
  list.add(i,s);
}

public boolean isExist(State s){
  for(Object state:list) if (state.equals(s)) return true;
  return false;
}

public boolean ExistOrSubsitute(State s){
  for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
    State state =list.get(i);
    if(state.equals(s)) {
        if(s.getEV()<state.getEV()){
          list.remove(i);
          InsertSorted(s);
        }
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```